# What is the best way to fetch data only once in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, fetch

so let's say I have a react dashboard application, which has several different routes. Now, one of those routes is `Analytics` route, and I was wondering, if is, what is the best way to fetch the data rendered in `Analytics` route only the first time you visit it and then pull it from **somewhere**.

I've been thinking about using `Redux` for it, but I've never used it, so I have no idea, OR if I should store it in `localStorage`. But that has a problem though, because on different route, I would like to fetch images the same way.

The reason I'm asking this is because I use `Firebase Firestore` as my DB and it could get quite costly, because I would have to do 4 read operations i.e. on the `Analytics` route each time it is rendered. Or, is it the normal approach?

Is it a good idea to use `React Context` and `useContext` hook in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use `localStorage` and it will be accessible on different routes of the same host.

Comment: @DmitriiZolotuhin yes, thank you. I thought about it and it may be the best approach, but what about the images?

Comment: it depends on how you get those images ofc. By default images are cached by the browser. If it is not the case for you - you can store those those in `localStorage` in base64 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **react-query** you can do exactly this in a much simpler way as compared to context or react-redux.

Answer (score 1):

use redux for state management, where you can store the application state and the components who need data. You can call Api in order to fetch data only first time in the root component of the app.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but wouldn't be better if I maybe used Context API, since my app is not **that** big?

Comment: if you are not planning to update the data or if you are not expecting your page to react to the changes in the data you can even use a Ref to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a useEffect hook and do an api call each time you visit that page and you don't have to store it anywhere and it will only get you the date you need i recently made an app and this way actually helped me alot